# why GainNode connections are not workinng?

Tags: audio, web-audio-api

I'm using Web audio API to get the frequency data from a sound file. Basically I have implemented the code showed in this [example](http://srchea.com/blog/2013/05/experimenting-with-web-audio-api-three-js-webgl/) what I want to add it is a `gainNode` so I can control the volume in any place of my code, but something is wrong with the connections I have made, everything else works just fine.

The volume part is the only thing I've changed from the original code:

```
request.onload = function() {
    context.decodeAudioData(
        request.response,
        function(buffer) {
            if(!buffer) {
                $('#info').text('Error decoding file data');
                return;
            }
            
            sourceJs = context.createJavaScriptNode(2048);
            sourceJs.buffer = buffer;
            sourceJs.connect(context.destination);
            analyser = context.createAnalyser();
            analyser.smoothingTimeConstant = 0.6;
            analyser.fftSize = 512;
            
            source = context.createBufferSource();
            source.buffer = buffer;
            source.loop = true;
            
            source.connect(analyser);
            analyser.connect(sourceJs);
            source.connect(context.destination);

                       //////////////////////////////////// 
                       //////////VOLUME////////////////////                            
                       gainNode = context.createGain();                        
                       source.connect(gainNode);                         
                       gainNode.connect(context.destination);
                       //////////////////////////////////////
                        
            sourceJs.onaudioprocess = function(e) {
                array = new Uint8Array(analyser.frequencyBinCount);
                analyser.getByteFrequencyData(array);
                boost = 0;
                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    boost += array[i];
                }
                boost = boost / array.length;
            };
            
            
            
            // popup
            //aca avisa cuando ya cargo el buffer
        },
        function(error) {
            $('#info').text('Decoding error:' + error);
        }
    );
};
```

Then I used this to turn off the volume but not working:

```
...gainNode.gain.value = 0;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the gain node to be the only thing that the output of `source` connects to.

Right now, it has multiple connections and your gain node is only one of them - which means it's not affecting your whole signal.